# can we catch two exceptions at once in java?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

i'm writing a code in java, and i came across this error:

```
try {
         //can't use the memberlist??


         System.out.println("Login successful! Welcome back!");

         member.memberProfile.setFirstName("Jane");
         member.memberProfile.setLastName("Doe");
         member.memberProfile.setAddress("123, Foster avenue, Chicago, US");
         member.memberProfile.setPhone("7735249286");
         member.memberProfile.setInterests("music");


        System.out.println("Do you wish to change your user information? Please type 'yes' or 'no': ");
        String choice= input.nextLine();

        if(choice.equals("yes")){
             member.memberProfile.Update_Details();
        }
        System.out.println("Your user information is: ");
        System.out.print(member.memberProfile.toString());

    } catch(UserNotFoundException | WrongAnswerException e ){
         System.out.println(e.getMessage());
         tries ++;
    }
```

I have a problem with the line `catch(UserNotFoundException | WrongAnswerException e )`
It says i need to remove either `UserNotFoundException` or `WrongAnswerException`
When i do, it says i have to remove the entire catch block. What can i do?

Comment: What is this `it`? And what's the exact error message `it` displays? Note that `try-multicatch` has only been in Java since version 7 so if your project is set to a lower Java version, you can't use it.

Comment: the `catch(a|b ex)` syntax was added in SE7. And WHAT is saying you have to remove the entire block?

Comment: Does that try block actually throw either of those exceptions?

Comment: @JohnKugelman No i didn't throw them, can you please show me how i can do that?

Answer (score 2):

If those are both checked exceptions (i.e. they aren't subclasses of `RuntimeException`) then the compiler will complain if none of the code in the `try` block throws those exceptions. It doesn't let you catch exceptions that static analysis shows are never thrown.

This is unrelated to the use of multi-catch `|` syntax.

Comment: I didn't make a RuntimeException class. However, i made those 2 exceptions classes. Can you please show me how to throw them and where?

Comment: @jungkookie That is a different question entirely. [Read the oracle tutorial here:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/)

Comment: @jungkookie Erm... "How" is `throw new WhateverException()`.  "Where" is wherever you need to.

Answer (score -3):

Your doing a logical OR

break up the catch block

```
}catch(UserNotFoundException userNotFound ){
        System.out.println(UserNotFound.getMessage());
        tries ++;
    }
}catch(WrongAnswerException wrongAnswer ){
        System.out.println(wrongAnswer.getMessage());
        tries ++;
    }
```

Comment: The `|` syntax is actually valid in java for exceptions.  (At least, usually; clearly OP is having an issue with it).